# Subscriber is unable to handler message from publisher

Tags: nservicebus

I'm testing NServiceBus on ASP.NET MVC3. At the moment, I'm able to send command message to the backend and the message handler is listening to it. But when i try to publish the same message, the message handler is not listening.

The problem i found is that message is not published to the subscriber's queue. When i debug and check NServiceBusHost console, it says

```
2012-01-19 22:53:35,042 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null
)> - Subscribing to SampleMessage.Person1WasCreated, SampleMessage, Version=1.0.
0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null at publisher queue Test-web
```

I checked my config settings again and again for few days and it seems correct for me . Can anyone please check for me what I'm missing? The thing I'm trying to do is to publish a message from the web and the message should be handle at the backend (ServiceHost2).

ASP.NET MVC3 Web.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
  </configSections>
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="Test-web" ErrorQueue="Test-web-error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5" />
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="Test-subscriptionstorage" />
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            Global.Bus = Configure.WithWeb()
               .Log4Net()
                .CastleWindsorBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .MsmqTransport().IsTransactional(false)
                .UnicastBus()
                .LoadMessageHandlers()
                .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                .CreateBus()
                .Start()
                ;
        }
```

App.Config in ServiceHost2 Project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="Service2-AC1-subscriptionstorage" />
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="Service2-AC1" ErrorQueue="Service2-AC1-Error" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="SampleMessage" Endpoint="Test-web" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EndpointConfigurationType" value="ServiceHost2.EndpointConfig, ServiceHost2"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

EndpointConfig for ServiceHost2

```
namespace ServiceHost2
{
    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            Configure.With()
                .Log4Net()
                .CastleWindsorBuilder()
                .MsmqTransport()
                .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .UnicastBus().LoadMessageHandlers()
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

Method in the controller which publish the message

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(Person p)
        {
            var Person1WasCreated = new Person1WasCreated {Id = p.Id,Name = p.Name};
            Global.Bus.Publish(Person1WasCreated);
            return View();
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong and your log output would appear that you are in fact subscribing to the event... are you sure it's not publishing? Check your subscription queue to see if there is a subscription maybe?

Comment: I double checked again and it is not there.It says i subscribed the message but there is no value in the subscription storage "Service2-AC1-subscriptionstorage". Very strange. FYI, im using NServiceBus 2.6

Comment: Subcribers are stored on the publisher side(your web site). Check the Test-subscrptionstorage queue?

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund , there is no message in Test-subscriptionstorage queue. Whenever I start the ServiceHost2 , I will keep on seeing this message : Subscribing to SampleMessage.Person
1WasCreated, SampleMessage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null at publisher queue Test-web.
Meaning, the message is not inside the queue. My ServiceHost.exe console stops at this line and never move at all : SubscriptionMessageType:SampleMessage.Person1WasCreated, SampleMessage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
=null, EnclosedMessageTypes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out why. I was reading on this article today about [Why not publish NServiceBus messages from a web application?](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/why-not-publish-nservicebus-messages-from-a-web-application/)

It states very clear that, message is not suppose to publish from the web. Somehow The subscription storage created by my web project doesn't allow anything to subscribe to it.

So my solution is, I send the command message from the web to a message handler in Service1, and publish a new event message to Service2. Even the event message is able to subscribe into Service1's subscription storage.Everything works fine now. Thanks.